# Standalone java class talking to a web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i'm working on a quite complex java web application based on Spring framework and hibernate,
i have to create a normal java class (with main method) and export it in a .jar file; this class contains a procedure that will be manually schedulated monthly by an operator.
the results of the scheduling will be consulted on the web app pages (JSP).

i need to use the jar file like this : java -jar myfile.jar arguments ....

is there a way to do this ?

how to export all the dependencies derived from spring and hibernate ?

P.S. i tried export the jar file with MyEclipse but when i try to run the jar, it can't find spring classes

Comment: if you need that why are you creating a web application ?

Comment: because the results of the scheduling will be consulted from the web app...

Comment: Still it is not a "Standalone java class in web application" but rather a "Standalone java class communicating a web application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the title is wrong, you need a standalone application.

Secondly, Every decent java IDE like should provide the option of exporting a jar. For example, in eclipse:

1. Right click the project
2. Choose export
3. Choose Runnable jar file

Another option is to use build tools like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: What are you talking about? This is a viable option for standalone applications and classpath issue exist if you use ant or maven as well. All classpath issue are not relevant to packaging the jar.

Comment: no maven or ant system implemented, i'm working on a project that has been created 5 years ago, we use myeclipse as IDE

Comment: Like i said, you can use the IDE option for packaging the jar, but for a serious system, it is recommended to have a build system, or at least a build script.

Comment: Myeclipse export doesn't work really good, executing the jar file i get, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Comment: That doesn't mean myeclipse is not working, it means that the jar you are trying to run depends on other jars, so either add the missing jars to your manifest Class-path property or in the command line

Answer (score 0):

Packaging dependencies is a topic which has no strict connection with Hibernate, Spring, Guice, or a Java library for generating random names for dogs.

- The first thing you need is a build system, which I hope you have if
  you are dealing with a quite complex java web application, and you
  are not letting your ide build.
- Once you have a build system such as Maven working correctly, you can
  look to the packaging extensions. In Maven, this is called assembly
  plugin.